# SQL Server 2008 r2 MDX GetDate()

Tags: sql-server-2008, mdx, ssas-2008

I am trying to determine what the language equivalent of `Select getdate()` is for MDX.

I want to simply get the date-time at the server in question, not actually query any data. This is for a kind of smoke test, so I need to understand the most simple statement I can make. I do not want to actually query any cube, because they all have different structures. I just need to get server level info by connecting to the server (not necessarily the data).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [How To Obtain the Current Day with a MDX Query or Expression in SQL Server 2000 Analysis Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301537):

The answer is:

```
-- The First Calculated member is the value of NOW()
WITH  MEMBER [Measures].[Full Date] as 'NOW()'
-- The Second Calculated Member is the Day part of the first calculated member.
MEMBER [Measures].[What Day] as 'DAY([Full Date])'
-- The Third Calculated Member is the Month part of the first calculated member.
MEMBER [Measures].[What Month] as 'MONTH([Full Date])'
-- The Fourth Calculated Member is the Year part of the first calculated member.
Member [Measures].[What Year] as 'YEAR([Full Date])'
SELECT
   {[Full Date],[What Day],[What Month],[What Year]} ON COLUMNS
FROM Sales
```

Result:

```
Full  Date   What Day        What Month     What Year
1:16:16 AM   19              9              2001
```

Article is for SASS 2000 but should run with 2008 R2.

Comment: Thanks but all cube names are different so I can't necessarily query any cube, I just need to get something in-memory from the server, which is why I used TSQL's GetDate() function as a sample. Thanks.

Comment: You can see in [MDX Select statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146002(v=sql.90).aspx) than `FROM` clause is mandatory. I don't know a way to get data from server withou this clause. Notice than [a calculated member that is created by using the WITH keyword no longer exists after the query has finished running](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187058(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: Something else that would work in TSQL is 'Select Top 1 * From [tablename] order by 1', what would the MDX equivalent of that be (I'm assuming I can always know the table name)? It's not the same as in my original question, but if MDX has a requirement to always have a named cube, maybe this will help get me where I need to go. Thanks.

Comment: This seems a great solution for your issue. Sure that you have a cube that can be append in FROM clause. Remember that this solution is taked from MS Support. I link to you another article, also works with cubes: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/05/23/how-to-get-the-today-s-date-in-mdx.aspx